# Удаление изображений

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в WPF удалить фотки из кэша? Потому что потом я не могу их редактировать, удалять. Если я хоть раз их загружу в программу, то потом из программы я их удалить не могу(удаление физически с жесткого диска). Получаю ошибку:

Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "D:\123.jpeg", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
if (!dirInfo.Exists)
{
    dirInfo.Create();
}
else
{
    ImageToOrderPackages = new ObservableCollection<ImageToOrderPackages>();
    foreach (var s in dirInfo.GetFiles("*.jpeg"))
    {
        ImageToOrderPackages.Add(new ImageToOrderPackages {ImageToOrderPackagesPuth = s.FullName});
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще ни как что ли?

Comment: В вопросе код на C#, следует ставить метку языка. Это лучше для вас, т.к. C# метка более популярная и просматривается большим числом участников. А вот к WPF вопрос мало относится (написали хотя бы, что у вас привязка к ImageToOrderPackages или что?)

Comment: @АндрейNOP  В старом примере было видно что вопрос относился к WPF(RealyCommand). И ты его то же перенес. Ладно не суть, моя ошибка то же есть, что не указал xaml и тд. На winform нет таких проблем со скриншотами. А тут есть, я гружу 50 фоток в listbox и он их все кэширует в память и не даёт ненужные удалять. Выход, что я сам их кэширую и могу теперь удалять. Но он не совсем подходит. Хотелось бы как то этого избежать и не нагружать оперативную память. Но пока не знаю как.

Comment: Я тело вопроса не правил (форматирование только), соответственно никакого `RealyCommand` там не было (убедиться можно посмотрев [ревизии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/849723/revisions)). В любом случае надо написать при чем тут WPF — вы используете привязки или что?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я про другой пост, не этот. Я его удалил. Тема поста была такая же.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Luka\Desktop\20170610_133017.jpg"))
{
    var bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Luka\Desktop\20170610_133017.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bi.EndInit();

    var ib = new ImageBrush(bi);
    Border1.Background = ib;
}
```

Решение с кэшем

Comment: Расскажите пожалуйста, как вам помог код в ответе

Comment: @Андрей NOP хватит переносить тему из WPF в C#.

А ответ прост, файлы загоняются в оперативную память, и тогда я могу удалять физически файл. По другому получаю ошибку что файл используется. Возможно есть другие способы, но судя по всему о них на форуме мне не расскажут.
Минус данного подхода, что если много фоток - съедается много оперативной памяти...